# A simple blog in Ruby on Rails not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to design a simple blog in RoR but the results are not what I expected. It involves just two tables a Post table and a Comments table.

I have put a `has_many :comments` in the **Post model** and `belongs_to :Post` in the **comment model**

In the post show template I have the following:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>
  <%= @post.title %>
</h1>
<p>
  <%= @post.body %>
</p>

<h2>Comments</h2>
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p><%= comment.comment %></p>
  <p><%= time_ago_in_words comment.created_at %> ago </p>
<% end %>

<%= form_for(@post.comments.create) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :comment %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

In the comments controller I have the following:

```
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.save
    redirect_to @post
end
```

My problem is that when I create a comment associated to, the page is redirecting to the comments page whereas I want it redirected to the post I commenting on. What I am doing wrong?

My environment is on a MacOs 10.8.2
RoR - 3.2.10
Ruby 1.9.3p362

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In show page of post

```
def show
 @post = Post.find(params[:id]
 @comment = @post.comments.new
end

In View
<%= form_for([@post,@comment])... %>

Routes File Contain 
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

now your comment controller has post_id in create action

```
CommentsController < ...
before_filter :load_post
def create
  @comment = @post.comments.new(params[:comment])
  .....
end

private
def load_post
 @post = Post.find(params[:post_id]
end
```

`@post.comments.create` will create actual comment object although you don't want create comment when every time show page hits,

Comment: This gives me an **can't convert nil into an exact number** error

Comment: hey dude remove first`@comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.save` from create it's part of comment controller you can redirect to post show page based on id as per my thought you should have nested resource

Comment: I think my problem might be in the routes file (going to change that soon). But I had a small question, isn't this kind of a hack: 

`private
def load_post
 @post = Post.find(params[:post_id]
end`

Comment: To answer your 'hack' question. No it isn't, it's a standard pattern in rails. Although if you only have one action, it might be better to call load_post directly from create as opposed to using a before_filter